# springfox swagger ui returning 404 for valid resource

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, springfox

I am getting 404 for valid resource request using swagger. Swagger is failing and returning me 404, while Postman is returning the result.
The parameter for which swagger is failing is the authDtls, I have to pass a json in this parameter, if I pass json then it's failing with 404, but working fine with a non json input.
I am using springfox swagger ui version 2.5.0

Is this a bug in swagger or springfox? Please suggest.

**Springfox Json:**

```
"/swaggerIssueReproduce": {
        "post": {
            "tags": ["preview-integration-controller"],
            "summary": "swaggerIssueReproduce",
            "operationId": "swaggerIssueReproduceUsingPOST",
            "consumes": ["multipart/form-data"],
            "produces": ["application/json"],
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "sourceArchive",
                "in": "formData",
                "description": "sourceArchive",
                "required": true,
                "type": "file"
            }, {
                "name": "authDtls",
                "in": "query",
                "description": "authDtls",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "mode",
                "in": "query",
                "description": "mode",
                "required": false,
                "type": "string"
            }],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Spring Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/swaggerIssueReproduce", method =  RequestMethod.POST,
consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE },
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity swaggerIssueReproduce(
       @ApiParam(required = true)
            MultipartFile sourceArchive,
       @RequestParam
            String authDtls,
       @RequestParam(required = false)
            String mode
) {
   LOG.info(" sourceArchive ###################" + sourceArchive);
   LOG.info(" authDtls ###################" + authDtls);
   LOG.info(" mode ###################" + mode);
   return new ResponseEntity("{\"_id\":\"Hello World\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

Comment: Please include the json you are sending

Comment: Below is the json I am sendiing,

       {
     "access_id": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9",
      "refresh_id": "eyJzdWIiOiI5MTAwMTIiLCJnc",
      "expires_in": 899,
      "scope": "write read",
       "jti": "0a45281e-8bef-4b6f"
          }

Comment: You're trying to send it JSON but your media type is `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`. This will not work.